# Why is cron job failing to send email when php mail()'s fifth parameter is included?

Tags: cron, php

I have a cron cron job setup to send emails. It is executed using the following command:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/cron/job.php
```

When I execute the php script from a browser, the script sends emails as expected. It fails when run by the cron job.

I don't see any errors in the maillog. Only difference is in the "from" line. When the script is executed from a browser, the log reads:

```
Jan 25 12:24:39 VMW01 qmail-remote-handlers[1001]: from=sender@domain.com
```

But when the cron job executes the script the "from" line becomes:

```
Jan 25 12:15:01 VMW01 qmail-queue-handlers[1000]: from=anonymous@VMW01.server.net
```

Oddly, the cron job will send emails when I remove the fifth parameter of the mail() line.

```
mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers, '-fsender@domain.com');
```

I would simply live with this, but if I remove the parameter, emails are often rejected by  servers - which I presume is because the parameter is not set.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it? I'd be happy to add more detail to this question in order to get to a solution.

Comment: Is the CLI loading a different php.ini than the web server perhaps? And if so, does one or the other of them have `mail.force_extra_parameters` specified? (I've never seen this problem before)

Comment: I would always advise to avoid using PHP's `mail()` function entirely; it can be incredibly difficult to work with and really hard to debug when it goes wrong. In virtually every case I've ever seen, it's better to use a decent third party library like phpMailer. It's always much simpler to write the code, usually works first time, and when it doesn't, it's much easier to work out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Michael said, most likely your cron job is using a different php.ini file. You can use the `php_ini_loaded_file()` function to see what file is loaded in your script - then run it from the command line, or your cron to see the difference with the web execution.

My guess is that the problem arises because the php.ini for the cron job (same as command line) has safe_mode set, and when that is the case, you shouldn't use the last parameter to the `mail()` function as it can fail. As evidence, if you look at the [`PHPMailer` class](http://svn.codespot.com/a/apache-extras.org/phpmailer/trunk/class.phpmailer.php) there is a `mail_passthru()` method that simply calls the PHP `mail()` function under the covers. Notice that it leaves out the extra parameter when not in `safe_mode`:

```
private function mail_passthru($to, $subject, $body, $header, $params) {
    if ( ini_get('safe_mode') || !($this->UseSendmailOptions) ) {
        $rt = @mail($to, $this->EncodeHeader($this->SecureHeader($subject)), $body, $header);
    } else {
        $rt = @mail($to, $this->EncodeHeader($this->SecureHeader($subject)), $body, $header, $params);
    }
    return $rt;
}
```

You can load a specific php.ini file when calling php from the command line (or your cron job) like this:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/cron/job.php -c /path/to/php.ini
```

Comment: This is getting me closer to a solution, I think. I just had to reorder the cmd line to get the php.ini to load: `/usr/bin/php -c /path/to/php.ini -q /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/cron/job.php`. Still, fifth parameter fails. I'm getting this error: "PHP Warning:  mail(): SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The fifth parameter is disabled in SAFE MODE". How to lift the safe mode restriction in calling the correct php.ini.

Comment: The `safe_mode` setting is in the `php.ini` file... you'll just need to change the path to the correct value for the location of your `php.ini` file, and of course, turn off the `safe_mode` setting - or not use the fifth parameter.

Comment: Not sure why, but php.ini used for web execution had safe mode set to off, despite web execution clearly not being in safe mode. I've gone ahead and set Safe Mode to "off". I presume there's no reason for having it on. mail() seems to be working now as expected from cron job.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I found changing my cron command to wget -O/dev/null http://myurl.com/ executed it just like in the browser would and email was sent.